# How to save information while moving through web pages?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I keep the information in a shopping cart if I move through pages, without the info being refreshed? Is it possible with just JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionStorage or localStorage to save some data in the browser if you just want to use Javascript. https://javascript.info/localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript cookies. For set cookies you can use a function like this:

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

And for read your cookie in other pages you can use this function:

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Also, I suggest you read [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for more details.